# How to get Larvel5.3 session data or Authentication data from public directory?

Tags: session, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I wrote some php function in public directory because I have to use external library. 
Then I can't retrieve any session data and authentication data from the controller I have tested with below php script

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
```

I have initial Session data from AdminMiddlware already
It awesome for using it in Resource->view directories but can not in public.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\User;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AdminMiddleware
{

/**
 * Handle an incoming request. User must be logged in to do admin check
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    $user = User::find(\Auth::user()->id);
    if ((int) $user->is_admin == (int) config('auth.guards.is_admin')) {

        $collection = collect(Auth::user());
        $thisdata   = $collection->toArray();
        $request->session()->put('user', $thisdata);

        return $next($request);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('/');

}}
```

Comment: Laravel doesn't use native sessions. Why aren't you able to use this `External Library` in your application?

Comment: I've include Rich File manager for upload and controlling to all media however I should keep those folder inside of public not resource directory that why I need to extend the LR53. session for checking whatever login user can access it.

Comment: there are no any solution to solved this case right?

Comment: Can you show the contents of the file (entire file) that you want to access the sessions from?

Comment: I have public this project to github you can below link

https://github.com/hengsoheak/personalEcommerce/blob/master/shop/public/gallery/connectors/php/filemanager.php

I use

//Testing session user data.
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION['user']);
//end testing session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the simplest way that I can see to get this to work with Laravel is:

(If you haven't done so already) Copy

```
public/gallery/scripts/filemanager.config.default.json
```

to

```
public/gallery/scripts/filemanager.config.json
```

Then set `"fileConnector"`(line 25) to `"/authenticate-filemanager",` e.g

```
"fileConnector": "/authenticate-filemanager",
```

This will tell your `Filemanager` application to load through the route `/authenticate-filemanager`.

Next, go to `public/gallery/connectors/php/application/FmApplication.php` and at the bottom change `if(!auth())` to `if(!auth()->check())` this will tell the application to use the built-in auth in Laravel.

Then you will need to set up the actual route (this is essentially the contents of `filemanager.php` without the `auth()` function):

```
Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], 'authenticate-filemanager', function () {

    require_once(public_path('gallery/connectors/php/application/Fm.php'));
    require_once(public_path('gallery/connectors/php/application/FmHelper.php'));

    $config = [];

    $fm = Fm::app()->getInstance($config);

    $fm->handleRequest();

});
```

Because both `GET` and `POST` calls are made to the same endpoint `match` is used. Make sure you don't put this route behind the auth middleware.

Lastly, you just need to to go to `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` and add `'authenticate-filemanager'` to the `$except` array to disable csrf for the route.

Hope this helps!

Comment: <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea', {
            filebrowserBrowseUrl: '{!! url('gallery') !!}',
            ImageBrowser : true,
            autoUpdateElement:true,
            language:'en'
        });
    </script>
on filebrowserBrowserURL should get that route or as the default?

Comment: @HengSopheak I don't know what that means, I've never used `CKEDITOR`. I just looked at the code enough that I'd be able to show you a way you could authenticate your users. I would suggest opening a new question. Also, if the above answer did solve you're auth problem please would you mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1):

Update for **RichFilemanger ver. 2.7.6** and **Laravel 5.6**

I use RichFilemanager in HTML text editor in admin panel. So check for admin user is logged in.

1. in public/../RichFilemanager/config/filemanager.config.json

   `"connectorUrl": "/admin/authenticate-filemanager",`
2. in route/web.php

   ```
   Route::match(['GET', 'POST'], '/admin/authenticate-filemanager', function () {

   //Here check is admin or user is authenticated. Can use: auth()->check()
   $isAuth = \App\Libraries\Admin\AdminBLL::isAuth();
   if(!$isAuth){
       return 'Not authenticated';
   }

   return require_once(public_path('assets/plugins/RichFilemanager/connectors/php/filemanager.php'));
   ```

   });
3. As was wrote before by Ross Wilson: Lastly, you just need to to go to `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` and add `'admin/authenticate-filemanager'` to the $except array to disable csrf for the route.
4. Last one - setup files folder location in `public/../RichFilemanager/connectors/php/filemanager.php`

   `$local->setRoot('userfiles/filemanager', true, true);`

Comment: Thank for your answer